# Deeplink to Spotify on a computer from Google Sheets on the web

Tags: google-sheets, uri, spotify, deeplink

I have a song URI (spotify: ...).

I'd like to be able to deeplink to the Spotify app on my computer from a cell in Google Sheets containing this URI (or the song name for example). I use Google Chrome on a Macbook pro.

I couldn't find how to do it - sheets/chrome don't interpret the spotify: scheme as a deeplink to the Spotify app - and of course the href link provided by Spotify opens the browser and not the Spotify app.

Is there a way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is currently not possible for the Spotify desktop app, but much discussed and demanded in their support forums and across the web. However, according to the moderator in the thread below, this is expected behaviour of the desktop app as of now and only possible on mobile.

https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Mac/Spotify-Links-quot-open-spotify-quot-don-t-open-in-Desktop-App/m-p/4870906#M540383

The only workaround I can think of is copy/pasting the Spotify URL from your Google sheet into the Spotify app's search bar manually to navigate directly to the song.